# A school offers 3 languages. 28 take Spanish, 24 take French, and 16 take German. 12 take S&F, 4 take S&G, 6 take F&G..

Tags: probability

$2$ take all three classes. What is the probability that a randomly selected student is taking exactly one language class?

Drawing a Venn Diagram does nothing and anyone who suggests that without further explanation should be punched in the face. This question is supposed to be answered using one of three formulas:

1) $P(E\cup F)=P(E)+P(F)-P(EF)$ and $P(E \cup F \cup G)= P(E)+P(F)+P(G)-P(EF)-P(EG)-P(FG)+P(EFG)$

2) $P(E)^c=1-P(E)$

3) $P(E)=\frac{\vert E \vert}{\vert S \vert}$

These were the only equations that we were shown in this chapter so as one user asked what is the probability that no one takes a class, well, it is precisely:

$P(E \cup F \cup G)^c=1-P(E \cup F \cup G)$

$=1-(P(E)+P(F)+P(G)-P(EF)-P(EG)-P(FG)+P(EFG)$

$=1-(.28+.26+.16-.12-.04-.06+.02)$

$=1-(.50)$

$=.50$

Now someone explain to me how this helps at all?

Comment: How many students are there in total? Or, said differently, are there any students that do not take any languages?

Comment: Draw a Venn Diagram

Comment: yes half do not take any languages

Answer (score 1):

Hint -

Draw venn diagram and start from intersection of all 3 events.

> Edit -

[image: page 1]

Comment: From your suggestion I cam to realize the following: 1) The number of people taking Spanish only is equivalent to$ 28+(-4-2-12)$ 2) The number of people only taking German is equivalent to $16+(-4-2-6)$ and Finally 3) The number of people only taking only French is equal to $26+(-12-2-6)$ So now where do I go from here?

Comment: which leads to a total of 10 only taking Spanish, 6 only taking French, 4 only taking German. For a total of 20 students only taking exactly one class

Comment: Sorry I am sleeping that time. I uploaded one pic. If you have any doubt then ask.